# Change initramfs script

Tags: boot, raid, mdadm, initramfs

I made RAID 0 by `mdadm'`ing partition located on dmraid [VIA VT6421](http://www.via.com.tw/en/products/peripherals/serial-ata_raid/vt6421/) and Western Digital hdd. Installed Ubuntu on that RAID. Now, when I boot, I get `(initramfs)` ash prompt.

There, I have to write

```
mdadm --stop /dev/md1
mdadm --assemble --scan
```

And hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to resume. Then Ubuntu loads normally.

I'd like to change that behavior to save my time. So, I need to change some script located in `/scripts` directory of initial ramdisk. But everything I know about `initramfs` is that it is gzipped. I looked into `update-initramfs` but didn't find the clue yet. Also, I'm afraid doing something there unless I know what I'm doing.

How do I change my initramfs script?

UPD: Now I know I should

```
gunzip -c initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic | cpio -id
```

Then make my changes and recreate it with

```
find . | cpio -o | gzip -c >/boot/initrd.new.img-3.13.0-24-generic
```

But I still don't know which scripts I should edit.

UPD2: `sudo parted -l`

```
$ sudo parted -l
Model: JetFlash Transcend 32GB (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 32,1GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start  End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      131kB  32,1GB  32,1GB  primary  fat32        boot, lba


Model: WD My Passport 074A (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  primary  ntfs


Model: ATA WDC WD1600JS-22M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 160GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  160GB  160GB  primary  linux-swap(v1)


Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!                           

Model: ATA WDC WD5000AAKS-0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sde: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start  End  Size  Type  File system  Flags


Error: /dev/mapper/via_ecedbfaihb6: unrecognised disk label               

Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/via_ecedbfaihb5: 524MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0,00B  524MB  524MB  ext4


Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!                           

Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/via_ecedbfaihb2: 167GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0,00B  167GB  167GB  ntfs


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/via_ecedbfaihb1: 367MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0,00B  367MB  367MB  ntfs


Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!                           

Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md1: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  6494MB  6493MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)
 2      6494MB  27,5GB  21,0GB  primary  ext4
 3      27,5GB  320GB   293GB   primary  ext4
```

Transcription:

- `/dev/sda` & `/dev/sdb` each of 500GB is fakeraid named `via_ecedbfaihb`,
- Win8.1 reserved partition on `via_ecedbfaihb1` (390MB),
- Win 8.1 system partition on `via_ecedbfaihb2` (160GB),
- extended partition `via_ecedbfaihb3`,
- linux boot partition `via_ecedbfaihb5` (500MB),
- mdadm 1st partition `via_ecedbfaihb6` (159GB),
- data partition `via_ecedbfaihb7` with the rest of space
- `/dev/sdc1` mdadm second partition (159GB),
- `/dev/md1` made of via_ecedbfaihb6 and sdc1,
- `/dev/md1p1` swap (6GB),
- `/dev/md1p2` extended,
- `/dev/md1p5` root (20GB),
- `/dev/md1p6` home (~300GB)

Comment: Wait, are you saying that you are using a via fakeraid with an md software raid stacked on top of that?  Why?  Can you provide the output of `sudo parted -l` for starters?

Comment: @psusi updated my question.

Comment: Why would you do that?  If you need to dual boot with Windows, use fakeraid, and otherwise, avoid it and just stick to mdadm.

Comment: @psusi I have speed increase about 20% comparing to only fakeraid.

Comment: What exactly is the configuration?  You should be able to do the same thing with just mdadm and it will work better.  dmraid is not well supported and so the only reason to use it is if you must dual boot with windows.